# Host name redirect to EC2 ip address on Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I am working on a Wordpress site. It works well, but when I enter a Wordpress page, it will be redirected to a new domain that has ec2 instance address as a part of it. I do not know why this happened? I have set up the correct domain name in Setting/General as well.
This website was built on an EC2 instance of AWS.

Thanks and look forward to hearing from you guys on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify few things if they are correctly set :

- Verify from wordpress admin dashboard if Settings >> General has correct domain. (You already did it).
- Check wp-config.php if it has domain configured in it.
- Check inside DB if the site url and home url are correctly set.
- Check if you have .htaccess and if there is any code carrying domain name apart from wordpress default code.
- If none of the above work I would suggest take dump of your database and search & replace the domain you are redirected to.

You can refer to link to verify few of the above :
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings

Answer (score 1):

Some database tables has that amazon's domain name. There can be two situations - fresh installation with no valuable posts and existing installation with posts.

**Fresh installation with no valuable posts**

For new installation, using a new database and running WordPress installer after deleting `wp-config.php` is easiest way if you have `wp-config` sample file. If `wp-config` sample file deleted then deleting the whole FTP root content and fresh wget to download WordPress, untar, then installation is practical.

**Existing installation with posts**

If that installation is existing with posts, you have to treat like changing domain name. There are WordPress plugins for it but SSH or PHPMyAdmin is reliable.

You need to run some MySQL queries from PHPMyAdmin or SSH to update the domain name like changing domain name or upgrading from HTTP to HTTTPS. Take a backup of that database first before running the commands :

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = "http://www.new-domain.com" WHERE option_name = "siteurl";

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://amazon-domain.com','http://new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://amazon-domain.com', 'http://new-domain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://amazon-domain.com','http://new-domain.com');
```

Long answer is written all over the earth for upgrading to HTTPS. Like this -- https://isabelcastillo.com/mysql-wordpress-http-to-https
Also add this to `wp-config.php` file :

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://your-site.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://your-site.com' );
```

For learning purpose, if you open that database SQL like text file, search that amazon's domain name in naked eye on text editor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create AWS account and create ec2 instance for same as follows:

   ```
   -> select Linux AMI
   ->t2.micro
   ->security groups must be http,secure group and custom tcp (3306 for mysql)
   ->key generate(.pem file)
   -> launch instances
   ```
2. on windows create .ppk file from pem using puttygen
3. login to your instance using putty

   ```
   host - ec2-user@xxxxxxxxxxxxx
   user - ec2-user
   ssh(auth)-ppk file

   connection ---> Success
   ```
4. after successful login perform these commands

   ```
   >[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update -y
   >sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
   >sudo service httpd start
   >sudo chkconfig httpd on
   >chkconfig --list httpd
   >ls -l /var/www
   > sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
   >sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
   >echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
   >http://my.public.dns.amazonaws.com/phpinfo.php
   >sudo yum list installed httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
   >rm /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
   >sudo service mysqld start
   >sudo mysql_secure_installation
   >sudo service mysqld stop
   >sudo chkconfig mysqld on
   >sudo yum install php70-mbstring.x86_64 php70-zip.x86_64 -y
   >cd /var/www/html
   >wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz
   >tar -xvzf phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz
   >http://my.public.dns.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin
   >chkconfig --list httpd
   >sudo yum remove -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd perl-DBD-MySQL56
   >sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
   >sudo yum remove -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd perl-DBD-MySQL55
   >from localhost go to settings->site settings -> change site and home url
   >export db(sql.zip)
   >login to phpmyadmin
   >import sql.zip here
   >from your project folder upload your code to git or bitbucket
   >now move to var/www/html
   >sudo git pull origin master
   > edit wp-config.php with your favorite text editor
   (sudo nano wp-config.php)
   >set values for db,db_name,db_host,db_user
   (db host should be ip for your instance)
   --Site is Live on host ip--
   ```